# Using a javascript config file for a handlebars blog template but config isn't working correctly

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, disqus, ghost-blog

I'm trying to add a config file for a blog theme I'm working on. Anyone who uses the theme would be able input variables in one place (ie: disqus shortname, google analytics UA code, etc.). I have everything finished up but for some reason it doesn't seem to be loading the config file. Here's what I have:

I have this in a file called "ichi-config.js" in the theme-name/assets/js folder :

```
// If you use DisQus comments, add your disqus shortname here
var config_disqus_shortname = 'barneycarney';
```

This is the javascript I have in a filed called "disqus.js" in the theme-name/assets/js folder which loads the comment section if they have input a shortname in the config file:

```
var disqus_loaded = false;

function load_disqus() {
    if (config_disqus_shortname !== '') {
        disqus_loaded = true;
        var disqus_shortname = config_disqus_shortname;
        var disqus_identifier = '{{post.id}}'; // make sure to use the post.id as an identifier, otherwise disqus will use the pages url per default, which might be problematic...

        // For embedding disqus under a post
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    }
}

load_disqus();
```

Then in the "post.hbs" file in the theme root folder I have:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script src="{{asset "js/disqus.js"}}"></script>
```

In the head portion of the "default.hbs" file, which is basically the template for all blog pages, I try to load the "ichi-config.js" script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset "js/ichi-config.js"}}"></script>
```

I've been over it a million times and I'm pulling my hair out trying to get it to work. Thanks in advance! If you want to look at the repository, you can find it over at:

https://github.com/Bernjc/ichi/tree/feature/theme-config

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it. It must have been the long hours coding the night before but when I setup the `config_disqus_shortname` variable originally, I had it as `config-disqus-shortname` which was causing problems. Works like a charm now!